# Grafana - How To plot the metrics for each variable which is passed dynamically

Tags: grafana

I'm using prometheus with grafana. I have a usecase where I have to take variables dynamically and need to perform divide operation which to be performed for each variable which is coming dynamically so can plot graph at each variable level.

eg. first metrics is -

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/",instance=~'${INSTANCE:pipe}'}[5m])
```

where ${INSTANCE:pipe} getting dynamically

which needs to be divided by -

```
machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname=~'${INSTANCE:pipe}'}
```

and i want result in format -

1 entry per variable

eg.

vars               result

var1             -     102

var2        -          23

var3          -        453

note (var1,var2,var3 are nothing but dynamically passed variables and result is nothing value return by divide operation)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: @trallnag it got solved! posted my approach check out if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying some queries found the solution -

My use-case has 2 metrics as below -

- container_cpu_usage_seconds_total
- machine_cpu_cores

In both metrics I found common label as `kubernetes_io_hostname`

I grouped both the metrics with the above label with the following queries -

- `(sort_desc ( max (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/",kubernetes_io_role="node"}[5m])) BY (kubernetes_io_hostname)`
- `sort_desc(max (machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_role="node"}) BY (kubernetes_io_hostname ))`

So my data has only 1 label named **kubernetes_io_hostname**

Then I did the division of the above 2 metrics and then got the result for the **kubernetes_io_hostname** label

If you need more info on this let me know in the comment section.